# Fit Images in MKMapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dictionary

I am using MKMapView , i want in my map the background image will display instead of map

i have some local images and i want that images will be shown instead of original map on 
MKMapView

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using CATiledLayer and a UIScrollView if you want to roll your own solution and need something pretty simple, or use https://github.com/route-me/route-me a native open source map library that enables you to use custom map tiles.